# How to default initilise a std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, initialization

Trying to default initialize a std::vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{    
    class Options
    {
        std::vector<int> items{100};
    } options ;

    std::cout << "Size:" << options.items.size() << " Items[0]:" << options.items[0] << '\n';

    return 0;
 }
```

This will print:

Size 1 : Items[0]:100

But that is not what I want, I want the vector to be of size 100.

I managed to do it with

```
class Options
{
    std::vector<int> items{ std::vector<int>(100) };
} options ;
```

But I get the feeling there must be a "better" way?

Regards,

Comment: @Evg That doesn't work for a class member

Comment: You want the two arg constructor (size and value] and you MUST NOT  use curly braces (which gives you brace-initialization)

Comment: The C++ standard `{}` constructors effectively initialize from a list of values, and you need `()` to call the other constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to initialize a class member in the body of the class is to brace or equal initialize it.  That means you can do

```
std::vector<int> items{ std::vector<int>(100) };
```

or

```
std::vector<int> items = std::vector<int>(100);
```

If you don't like either of those options then you can add an initializer to the classes constructor and have

```
class Options
{
    Options() : items(100) {}
    std::vector<int> items;
} options ;
```

but personally I would use the first two options instead.

Comment: @Slava What uniform initialization? ;)  It's pretty good if you start off building your type to support it, unfortunately that is not the case for the standard types that were built in a time when that interface wasn't possible.

Comment: "Pretty good" is not enough. It creates more problems than it solves, and problems it creates are worst possible - silently change behavior when you change data type.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you elaborate on this? How would one change the vector to make it work better with the new syntax?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Basically it would be to remove those constructors.  We can't do that though so we live in a world with no good solution.  An "easy" fix would be to add tags to those constructors that cant be differentiated from the initializer list so you can still brace initialize and use the tag to select the constructor you want.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid any confusion due to differing behavior between

```
std::vector<int> items(100);
```

and

```
std::vector<int> items{100};
```

use

```
std::vector<int> items;
items.resize(100);       //Default initializes 100 int <=> zero
// or
items.resize(100, 17);   //Initializes 100 ints with value 17
```

Used in a constructor

```
class Options
{
    std::vector<int> items;

public:
    Options()
    {
        items.resize(100);
    }
} options;
```

Comment: Do note that this can't be done with an in class member initializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Options
{
    std::vector<int> items;
public: 
    Options() : items(100) {}
}
```

The `:` starts the list initialization of the members, constructing the members in the order they're declared in the class, before the constructor body starts.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as follows :

```
std::vector<int> items(100,0);
```

This will create vector with size 100 and initialized all with value 0

Comment: OP can't put this at class scope though.